# Mathematics in eclipse (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, math

I have created my app and all that and when I run it it works fine. 
But when I press calculate(button) it calculates (X * Y / Z)(X & Y & Z = USER INPUT) but the app chrashed when I press calculate. The LOGCAT give me this upon 
Start:

```
    01-18 23:42:06.265: D/SensorManager(29893): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41c60ed0
01-18 23:42:06.265: D/Sensors(29893): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
01-18 23:42:06.265: I/Sensors(29893): sendDelay --- 200000000
01-18 23:42:06.265: D/SensorManager(29893): JNI - sendDelay
01-18 23:42:06.265: I/SensorManager(29893): Set normal delay = true
01-18 23:42:06.335: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:42:06.335: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:42:06.335: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:42:11.505: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:42:11.510: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:42:59.375: D/SensorManager(29893): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41c60ed0
01-18 23:43:02.000: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:43:02.000: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:43:02.000: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:43:03.550: D/SensorManager(29893): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41c60ed0
01-18 23:43:03.550: D/Sensors(29893): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
01-18 23:43:03.550: I/Sensors(29893): sendDelay --- 200000000
01-18 23:43:03.555: D/SensorManager(29893): JNI - sendDelay
01-18 23:43:03.555: I/SensorManager(29893): Set normal delay = true
01-18 23:43:03.720: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29893): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-18 23:43:15.335: E/SensorManager(31807): thread start
01-18 23:43:15.340: D/SensorManager(31807): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41c5aba0
01-18 23:43:15.345: D/SensorManager(31807): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41c5aba0
01-18 23:43:15.345: D/Sensors(31807): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
01-18 23:43:15.345: I/Sensors(31807): sendDelay --- 200000000
01-18 23:43:15.350: D/SensorManager(31807): JNI - sendDelay
01-18 23:43:15.350: I/SensorManager(31807): Set normal delay = true
01-18 23:43:15.365: D/SensorManager(31807): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41c5aba0
01-18 23:43:15.395: D/libEGL(31807): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-18 23:43:15.395: D/libEGL(31807): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-18 23:43:15.400: D/libEGL(31807): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-18 23:43:15.405: D/(31807): Device driver API match
01-18 23:43:15.405: D/(31807): Device driver API version: 10
01-18 23:43:15.405: D/(31807): User space API version: 10 
01-18 23:43:15.405: D/(31807): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
01-18 23:43:15.445: D/OpenGLRenderer(31807): Enabling debug mode 0
01-18 23:43:15.335: E/SensorManager(31807): thread start
```

And on chrash:

```
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method calculateClickListener(View) in the activity class tk.iWeld.iweld.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'resultbutton'
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3678)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: calculateClickListener [class android.view.View]
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3671)
01-18 23:43:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(31807):    ... 11 more
```

I see the problem but I do not understand it...
(Lets not get too much quotes in here, shall we?)
MainActivity.java: http://pastebin.com/41niS5AF
activity_main.xml: http://pastebin.com/PVLq4t9t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace is self-explanatory :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: calculateClickListener
```

There is no method named `calculateClickListener(View v)` in your activity.

Either change in your xml:

```
android:onClick="calculateClickListener"
```

to

```
android:onClick="calculateClickHandler"
```

---

Or in your java code :

```
public void calculateClickHandler(View view)
```

to

```
public void calculateClickListener(View view)
```

Comment: Okay thanks, now it doesnt chrash, but now it doesnt happen anything at all when you press the button? :s

Comment: @user3210676 Do you enter in your if condition? Try to print to the log to see what happends.

Comment: I pasted my code, take a look at it. I am pretty sure... or what do you mean?

Comment: @user3210676 Does `(view.getId() == R.id.resultbutton)` evaluated to true?

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do this?

Comment: Add this in the if statement : `Log.d("Message", "In the if!");`. It will print "in the if!" in the logcat.

Comment: I checked the "Session  Filter" and nothing shows up, theres nothing different from the logcat i pasted.

Comment: @user3210676 Do you mean? There is an error? Try to remove the `if()`.

Comment: I meant that nothing shows up in the Logcat (regarding the message) and if I remove the if statement I get like 3 errors

Comment: @user3210676 You can let the if statement. Your code works perfectly for me (finally I tested it because your issue is not resolved apparently). Show me your updated code.

Comment: The button works for you? wth, I have not changed the code excet for what the guy above said

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4uREfrPD
http://pastebin.com/kkymbeUN
http://pastebin.com/xbjLg6Md

Comment: @user3210676 Your code is working for me (I just removed 
    `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"` in your xml) since I didn't defined those dimension. Did you get an error? An exception?